# How to see if a user didn't input a valid entry in C#

Tags: c#, loops

I was wondering how to output if a user entered an invalid entry in the code below. For example, if they entered string characters or a combination of string characters and a number. Right now it just breaks the program if an invalid entry is entered. Please keep the answer to what the most basic way is, as I am fairly new to programming!

```
 Console.Write("Please enter the persons age: ");
 int age = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
 if(age == 17)
 {
     Console.WriteLine("That's to bad! You will have to wait until next year!");
 }    
 else if (age < 18)
 {
     Console.WriteLine("That's to bad! You will have to wait a couple years until you can come in!");
 }
 else
 {
     Console.WriteLine("You are of age to be here.");
 }

 while (true)
 {
     Console.Write("Please enter the next persons age: ");
     age = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

     if (age == 17)
     {
         Console.WriteLine("That's to bad! You will have to wait until next year!");
     }
     else if (age < 18)
     {
         Console.WriteLine("That's to bad! You will have to wait a couple years until you can come in!");
     }
     else if (age > 18)
     {
          Console.WriteLine("You are of age to be here.");
     }
     else
     {
          Console.WriteLine("Please enter a valid entry");
     }
 }
```

Comment: Int.TryParse is your friend

Comment: You can use `Int.TryParse` to see if you have a valid integer. Alternatively for problems similar to this that not only use digits but strings as well, you could look into [Regular Expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/regular-expression-language-quick-reference). Regular expressions can allow you to check for a specific pattern of characters (such as only numbers 0-9).

Comment: Note: int should be lowercase (as you have in your code) or it should be Int32.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a question for professional or amateur programmers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do:

```
int age;

if (int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out age))
{
    if (age > 17)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("That's too bad! You will have to wait until next year!");
    }
    // etc
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Please enter a valid input");
}
```

**Explanation**:

`int.TryParse` is a method that takes an `string` and tries to convert it to an `int`, if the conversion was successful it assigns the result to the `age` variable and returns true causing the program to enter the `if` block, otherwise returns `false` and the program enters the `else` block. The `age` variable is assigned by making use of C#'s [output parameters feature](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/out-parameter-modifier) which is a way of passing a variable from *outside* to a method while the latter promises it will assign some value to it.

Answer (score 1):

you can try to use `int.TryParse` function to check user input is or isn't number, that will return a `bool` value

- `true` user input is a number.
- `false` user input isn't a number.

I would use `do ... while` instead of `while`, because that can let your code clearer.

```
int age;
do {
    Console.Write("Please enter the persons age: ");

    if (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out age)){
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter a valid entry");
    }
    else if (age == 17)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("That's to bad! You will have to wait until next year!");
    }
    else if (age < 18)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("That's to bad! You will have to wait a couple years until you can come in!");
    }

}
while (true);
```